# Optical activity of cis-trans isomers of a co-ordination compound

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, stereochemistry, optical-properties, cis-trans-isomerism

Why do geometrical (cis and trans) isomers of *[Pt(NH3)(Br)(Cl)(py)]* not show optical activity ? Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Because each of them is a superimposable mirror image of ***itself***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement of isomers of $\ce{[Pt(NH3)Br Cl py)]}$ giving non-superimposable mirror images is incorrect. Bottom line is, if they are not  they are non-superimposable mirror images, then they should be opticlly active. Basically all three possible geometrical isomers of said compound are suire planner and have superimposable mirror image of each. I have graphically illustrate one of them it for your benefit:

[image: Geometrical isomers of [Pt(NH3)(Br)(Cl)(py)]]

Suppose three isomers, **I**, *II*, and *III*, respective mirror images of **I'**, *II'*, and *III'*. Consider only mirror image **I'**. If you rotate it $90^\circ$ *anti*-clockwise around the axis perpendicular to the paper, you get the structure **I"**. Now flip structure **I"** around the dioganal axis indicated ($100^\circ$). Now you got the structure **I** back, meaning the isomer **I** and its mirror image are identical.